# Increase virtual hard disk size for Fedora 10 VM

Tags: hard-drive, fedora, vmware-server, bios

I currently have a Fedora 10 VM on VMWare. I'm out of space on the Fedora 10 hard drive and need to allocate more; so far I've been following [these instructions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-resize-vmware-virtual-harddisk-size.html). A quick summary is:

- shut down running VM, go to options and increase disk capacity. For myself, I simply set it in Settings -> Hard Disks, rather than going to command line.
- download Gparted, set VM's CD/DVD drive to load Gparted's iso file, and then set the VM to boot from CD
- Resize the partition using Gparted

I'm stuck on the 2nd step: when I attempt to press F2 on startup, I cannot get to the VMware BIOS menu. When I press F2, I only see various versions of Fedora. Can anyone help me help on this? Is there another completely different way to increase the size of the partition?

Edit: Looks like I had to press 'esc' rather than f2 to get to bios setting. Also, since my partition is LVM type, GParted couldn't resize because it doesn't support that type. Luckily, LVM has built-in resizing functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bring up the boot menu during POST, press ESC. If it flies by too quick and you miss it, there is an option to delay the boot to give you enough time to hit it. It's under the VM's properties, but I can't remember what the tab is called.

Good luck! Hopefully you aren't running LVM, because that is not as simple to expand/extend.

Answer (score 2):

For step 2, here's an easy solution:

In vCenter (or on the host directly from the vSphere Client), click on the machine in question.
Click on the Summary tab.
In the Commands box, click Edit Settings.
Click on the Options tab.
Select "Boot Options"
Check the box in Force BIOS Setup to have the machine go into the BIOS at the next boot.
Click OK to save.

Once the configuration change is completed, you can power off (if needed) and power back on the machine - it will default into the BIOS for you. You can change the boot order to prioritize the CD before the HD.

Also, I assume you are aware but in the Hardware tab in that same editing screen, CD/DVD Drive 1, this is where you will point the CD to mount an ISO. Also, check the boxes above (Device Status) for both Connected and Connect at power on. I was personally very frustrated trying to get the machine to boot to a CD until I figured this one out...

Hope this helps!
Jes

Answer (score 0):

u can use convirt tool to do that